# Scala - doing something extra in for comprehension on None

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, lift

Sorry for the bad title

Basically I have a db query that returns `None` or `Some`

I want to do a for comprehension over it

```
val sentMessage = for {
      action <- actionO;
      user <- userO;
      message <- messageModel.findByActionID(action.id)
    }
```

But the "extra" something for None; is to do some logging

So (psuedo code)

```
val sentMessage = for {
      action <- actionO if actionO is undefined Log("We could not find user)
```

Lift web has the type Box; which has this feature
http://simply.liftweb.net/index-7.2.html

```
id <- S.param("id") ?~ "id param missing" ~> 401
```

I'm currently using Play - so perhaps there is somthing in there I could leverage?

EDIT - using orElse I now have; can this be cleaned up any more?

```
 val sentMessage = for {
      action <- findByName(actionName).orElse({Logger.error("Can't find action by name " + actionName); None});
      user <- userModel.findByPk(userID).orElse({Logger.error("Can't find user by id " + userID); None});
      } yield {
      val channels
```

Thanks

Comment: With `Option`, `.getOrElse` or `.orElse` can be used to fallback (or `if (opt.isDefined) ...`).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried orElse; I've edited my question; is there any way to do it slightly cleaner?

Comment: A `Try` might fit better, then you can match on it afterwards and log any `Failure`. Assuming you had control of the API or could transform it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fold to convert an `Option` to a `Try`:

```
intOpt.fold[Try[Int]](Failure(<some exception>))(Success(_))
```

Then when you're processing your results you just match on the `Try`, act on the successes, and log on the failures.

```
// dummy function acting like your db lookup
def sometimesWorks(i: Int): Option[Int] = i match {
  case 1 => Some(i)
  case _ => None
}

// function to convert an Option bearing something to a Try
def asTry[T](in: => Option[T], reason: String): Try[T] = {
  in.fold[Try[T]](Failure(new RuntimeException(reason)))(Success(_))
}

val ints = Vector(0,1,2)
val trys = ints.map((x) => asTry(sometimesWorks(x), "Failed due to sometimesWorks."))

trys.map { t =>
  // Try can be used in the comprehension as well, will propogate errors.
  val result = for {
    x <- t
    y = x * 3
    z = y + 20
  } yield z

  // use a match on the results
  result match {
    case Success(v) => println(s"Worked: $v")
    case Failure(e) => println(s"Logging failure: ${e.getMessage}")
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
Logging failure: Failed due to sometimesWorks.
Worked: 23
Logging failure: Failed due to sometimesWorks.
```

Comment: `Try` is not very typesafe, and throwing an exception is inefficient. It would be better to use e.g. scalaz `\/`: `findByName(actionName).toRightDisjunction("Can't find action by name " + actionName")`

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately exception use is predicated by the use of `Try`. I tend to not suggest adding libraries like scalaz unless someone expresses displeasure with the core library functionality (or expresses a desire for stronger typing, like you suggest). Still better than `Option` if you actually care about the failure. In my opinion, `None` is not a failure - it's the absence of value, which can be a real answer for some algorithms. I.e. if a map doesn't contain a key, that doesn't mean the map is in an error state.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using an `Either` is this case.  By convention you often hold an error message in `Left` and the successful value in `Right`.  You can convert an `Option` to an `Either` by doing:

```
val myEither = myOption.toRight("This is an error message")
```

Then you can use an `Either` in a for comprehension as:

```
val transformed = for {
    x <- myEither.right
} yield x * 3
```

And then you can propagate this error message for as long as you want, and print it when it suits you.